# Is 58 mm Metal Tele Lens Hood is fine for 18-55mm lens canon?

Tags: lens, canon

I have 18-55mm and a 58mm lotus hood on it but the problem is that when i capture photos from my canon 700D on 18mm focal length the hood also showing in my frame of pictures. i want to buy a 58mm hood (not lotus) will it also come into my frame while taking pictures? here's the hood i want to put on my 18-55mm

[image: this is the hood i want to put on my 18-55mm]

Answer (score 6):

Which lens do you have?

EF-S 18-55 IS II

or

EF-S 18-55 STM

Either way, don't use a 58mm screw in telephoto metal lens hood like the one in your photo. It will vignette badly at 18mm.  Even if you were to use the shallower "wide angle" 58mm metal hood, it would still strongly vignette at 18mm.

I have one and made a sample of what it would look like.....

[image]

[image]

If you have the EF-S 18-55 IS II, don't get a 3rd party "petal" or "lotus" type hood either. The older 18-55's all have a rotating front section so any type of "petal" hood will also show up as the hood rotates during focus or zooming.

The only hood you can use on your Canon 18-55mm IS or IS II lens is the Canon EW-60C or a 3rd party equivalent.

[image]

If you have the newer 18-55mm STM lens, the correct hood is a Canon EW-63C or 3rd party equivalent.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the EW-63C not have a flocking lining? The inside of the hood in the last photo is way too reflective!

Comment: No flocking. It seems Canon has gone away from flocking for their newer “Consumer “ lenses. I have the 50 STM, 18-55 STM, and 55-250 STM. They all have lens hoods that have no flocking.  The 18-135 STM is an exception because  it uses  the EW73B, which dates back to the EF 17-85 USM, and it does have flocking.

Comment: what about 49mm metal Lens hood?

Comment: 49mm will not fit the 58mm filter threads of your lens, but even if it did fit, because it is a smaller diameter, it would cause even more vignetting.

Comment: Is there any other lens hood for 18-55mm STM not in lotus?

Comment: Not that I am aware of....

Comment: @MikeSowsun Thank you bro for your help you solved my problem.